# AlarmManager.setExact() possible Error warning NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, warnings, alarmmanager

I am trying to learn how to use the AlarmManager in Android so I am new to the AlarmManager class but not to Java. 
I am using Android Studio 3.1.3.
I am receiving a warning in the Editor when using AlarmManager.setExact().

The code:

```
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent("delayed");
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis() + (120 * 1000), alarmIntent);
```

I have run this code succesfully triggering an Alarm 2 seconds from the current time.

The warning is highlighted over the "setExact" part and makes no sense to me so I was wondering if anybody can shed some light on this for me please.

The Warning/Error:

```
    Method invocation 'seExact' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'
```

I understand generally what a NullPointerException is, but I cannot figure out what is written in my code that is a potential for that specific Exception?

Answer (score 0):

That warning is telling you about a *possible* `NullPointerException`. If it cannot cast the return value from `getSystemService` as an `AlarmManager` or if it returns null then `alarmMgr` will be null from this line:

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

and will be null when you try to use it on the later line. To avoid the warning, you could check for null first before using it:

```
if( alarmMgr != null ) {
     alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis() + (120 * 1000), alarmIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getSystemService()` return type is annotated `@Nullable`, and attempting to invoke  a method on a nullable is a potential NPE.

You can suppress the warning as to not care about the potential NPE with

```
//noinspection ConstantConditions
alarmMgr.setExact(...);
```

or add a null check to ensure strict non-nullity at runtime. I prefer [`Objects.requireNonNull()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T)) for such in Java for API 19+.